# What are the substitutes for "it should be noted that", "consider" and "As it was mentioned previously"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Could you please tell me what are the good substitute for

> - It should be noted that?
> - Consider
> - As it was mentioned previously

I don't want them to be repeated many times.

Comment: You could try leaving it out altogether.

Comment: Sorry I did'n get your mean?

Comment: Are you sure you need to say things like 'It should be noted that' at all? Try leaving it out and see if it makes any difference to the meaning of what you are writing.

Comment: Because it's a paper, it needs some of these kinds of empesizes. I may leave one or two of them, It seem imposible to leave all of them. By the way,  I don't think I can leave the word consider at all...

Comment: OK, just a suggestion. It's your paper.

Comment: _I draw your attention to_ - ***consider*** reminds me of http://youtu.be/9czBBKof7Yo?t=1m22s

Comment: All three constructions are over-used and deliver limited information.  They are phrases that English composition don't want to see.

Answer (score 2):

How about "[take into account](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-sth-into-account?a=british)" which means:

> to ​consider or ​remember something when ​judging a ​situation: '*I ​hope my ​teacher will take into account the ​fact that I was ​ill just before the ​exams when she ​marks my ​paper.*'

[Cambridge Online Dictionary]

Comment: I don't know why someone down-voted me here. Mamal asked for alternatives for his phrases and I provided one. And according to Cambridge dictionary it is perfectly fine: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/take-sth-into-account